# using ISNUMERIC() with sql_variant SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I use `ISNUMERIC()` function with `sql_variant` datatype?

This following code doesn't work

```
DECLARE @x sql_variant 
SET @x = 3 
IF ISNUMERIC(@x) = 1 
 SELECT 'Numeric'
 ELSE
SELECT ' NOT'
```

Error :

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of isnumeric function.

But this works

```
IF ISNUMERIC(CAST(@x AS INT)) = 1
```

is there is any way of making this happened with out `CAST()`

Haven't found any thing useful on google regarding this issue thanks , I'm using 
SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Are you trying to check if the _value_ is numeric, or if the _underlying datatype_ is a numeric type? For example, should the `NVARCHAR` '3' be deemed numeric?

Comment: well Filip Answer works with the situation i'm having now but it still doesn't make sense this to call this @x = '123' Numeric right ?

Comment: **watch out, ISNUMERIC() doesn't always "work" as you expect it to.** see: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/01/13/isnumeric-broken-only-up-to-a-point/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if the *underlying datatype* is numeric, you can use [`SQL_Variant_Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx) to find out;

```
DECLARE @x sql_variant 
SET @x = 3.2

SELECT CASE 
       WHEN SQL_Variant_Property(@x, 'Precision') = 0 
       THEN 'NO' 
       ELSE 'YES' 
       END
```

Answer (score 4):

Casting to `int` doesn't really make sense. Your conversion will fail (when something else than an integer appears) and you'll get an error.

You can, however, cast to `nvarchar(max)` - this *should* always work and your `ISNUMERIC` function will behave as expected